# Uncaught TypeError: .map is not a function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I have web application with knockout js. i want to implement autocomplete textbox using knockoutjs

i found following link to implement it

http://jsfiddle.net/5PRMe/

i copied following code:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.users = remoteData;

    self.selectedOption = ko.observable('');
    self.options = self.users.map(function (element) {
        // JQuery.UI.AutoComplete expects label & value properties, but we can add our own
        return {
            label: element.name,
            value: element.id,
            // This way we still have acess to the original object
            object: element
        };
    });
}
```

but i am getting an error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: self.users.map is not a function
```

how to solve this error ?

Thanks

Comment: if you do `console.log(self.users)`  or `console.log(remoteData)`  what do you see? I imagine `self.users` is not an array

Comment: Your code expects that `remoteData` will be an array, and it isn't.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald: Better yet, rather than stumbling around with a `console.log` torch, the OP should use the debugger to turn on the lights.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you said it! :-) tbh im only wandering around with a box of matches in the form of `console.log`. Need to start turning those lights on myself!

Comment: Doesnt help that the fiddle you're using for your example of how to do this itself has a bug (`Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`). Its a different error to what you're getting. Please provide us a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.